# MySQL Query for book cost of a class

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I just need a single MySQL line query for the following.

Lets say there are 2 simple tables: **`Class`** and **`Books`**

**`Class`**
`ID--Name-----Students`
1------KG-----------20
2------Grade(3)---25
3------Grade(5)---30

**`Books`**
`ID--ClassId--Title-------------Cost`
1-----1--------------Drawing------------------5
2-----3--------------History--------------------25
3-----1--------------A-to-Z--------------------10
4-----2--------------Alphabets---------------20
5-----3--------------Maths--------------------15
6-----2--------------English-------------------30

Lets say:
What we only know is -----> **`ID`** of the **`Class`**
What we have to find is ---> **Book Cost of a class.** (Books for Each Students In A Class)

**Can I just have a Single Line of Query for it?**

Comment: `Book Cost` by calculating with `Students Count` in a given `Class`. (Sorry everyone if i didn't mentioned the question clearly)

Comment: thats why its always a good idea to include the sample of expected output :)

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add the [homework] tag

Comment: Actually not, RMorrisey. I'm having trouble on the project. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

**In Single Line:**

```
SELECT SUM(Class.Students * Books.Cost) AS BookCost  FROM Books INNER JOIN Class       ON Books.ClassId = Class.ClassId WHERE Books.ClassId = <CLASS-ID-VALUE>  GROUP BY Books.ClassId
```

**With formatting:**

```
SELECT SUM(Class.Students * Books.Cost) AS BookCost
  FROM Books INNER JOIN Class
   ON Books.ClassId = Class.ClassId
WHERE Books.ClassId = <CLASS-ID-VALUE>
GROUP BY Books.ClassId
```

Comment: Ah, `Book Cost` by Calculating with `Students Count` in given `Class`. (Sorry if i didn't mentioned the question clearly)

Comment: +1, the updated answer worked it out for you :). I would have done `SUM(Books.Cost) * Class.Students` but the difference is not noticeable.

Comment: Yes, Cybernate, this is great and works. Please help my another step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784054/help-another-harder-mysql-query

Answer (score 4):

```
   SELECT c.Name,
          SUM(b.Price * c.Students) cost
     FROM Class c
LEFT JOIN Books b ON b.ClassId = c.ID
    WHERE c.Students >= 31
 GROUP BY c.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

`SELECT SUM(cost) AS cost FROM Books WHERE ClassId=? GROUP BY ClassId`

Where the question makr is either the ID of the class or part of a prepared statement where you feed it the class ID.

You can retrieve the sum with column name "cost".

Comment: Ah, `Book Cost` by Calculating with `Students Count` in given `Class`. (Sorry if i didn't mentioned the question clearly)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select c.classId, sum(b.cost) as TotalCost,sum(c.students) as TotalStudents from books as b, class as c where b.classId = class.Id and c.Id = YourKnowClassId group by c.Id;
```

Comment: Ah, `Book Cost` by Calculating with `Students Count` in given `Class`. (Sorry if i didn't mentioned the question clearly)

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(c.Name) as Name, sum(b.Price * c.Students) as Cost
from Class c
left join Books b on b.ClassId = c.ID
where c.Students >= 31
group by c.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like:

```
SELECT C.Name AS ClassName, SUM(B.Price) * C.Students AS BookCost
  FROM Class AS C INNER JOIN
       Books AS B ON C.ID = B.ClassId
  WHERE C.ID IN (SELECT ID
                   FROM Class
                   WHERE Students >= 31
                   ORDER BY Students ASC
                   LIMIT 1)
  GROUP BY C.ID;
```