# MySQL Query Question

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help! MySQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783597/help-mysql-query)

Consider 2 simple tables:

`Class`
ID---Name---Students
1----KG-----20
2----G(3)---25
3----G(4)---35
4----G(5)---30

`Books`
ID---ClassId---Title-------Price
1-----1--------Drawing-----5
2-----1--------A-to-Z------10
3-----2--------Alphabets---20
4-----2--------English-----30
5-----3--------Maths-------15
6-----3--------History-----25
7-----4--------History-----30

What we will input is ---> `Student Count`
The question is ---------> Get class(es) by returning `Books Cost` which class has <= `Student Count`
Please Note -------------> Book Cost will be calculated for **each** student in a class
Test Sample -------------> Input 31 Students will result G(4) class and it has 1400 Book Cost

Can this be done in a single query?